# War Thunder: Are bombers really important to winning?

Tags: war-thunder

I started playing War Thunder recently and heard bombers where vital to winning, but it seems to me that the only way bombers can help win is to either take down both carriers or *all* ground/naval units. Since the biggest bomb load doable seems to be about 6000lb and each carrier takes that, AND there are far more ground units than a bomber can take out in even 3 trips, AND (even the toughest of heavy) bombers are often taken down within the first 5 minutes, never given a chance to come close to reach the enemy carriers or 1/2 of the ground units, it seems to me that bombers are almost totally useless to winning the game in Realistic mode and their positions would be better served by fighter jets who could help kill off the other team to win.

I've yet to see a Realistic mode game won by bombers. **So, are bombers really important to winning?**

Perhaps I'm wrong, afterall I am new to the game. This is just what I've found so far.

Comment: yes they are very important.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, bombers are important

I don't know specifics on how hitting ground targets is actually scored, but bombers are indeed valuable. As you've noted the problem is that they can get wiped out pretty quickly by opposing forces.

### Bombers and Bases

When you play as a bomber you can drop bombs on the opposition bases. Currently each match usually has three opposition bases. Once you've knocked these out, you can then strike at the opposition airfield.

The opposing team loses points for each base lost, and if you knock out the airfield, it will cause the opposition's life meter to begin dropping. If bombers can take out the enemy airfield, the game will end within seconds.

Over *War Thunder*'s life, the developers have experimented a bit with the "hit points" the bases have. In some earlier releases the bases were stronger. As of this writing, the three smaller bases on each map are a bit weaker but the enemy airfield can take a lot of damage.

### Other ground targets

All ground targets are worth some points to you. Some, like tanks and boats are worth a lot more and will cause the opposing team to lose points. On some maps that have no main airfield, taking out the ground targets are often the main objective. Even on maps with bases that haven't been destroyed, I have seen games where knocking out the other ground targets can accelerate a victory.

Comment: As of now, each base requires 5.25 tons of TNT to destroy. The value you're credited with decreases as you get further away from the marked point, so you need to drop 7-9 Tons fairly accurately to be certain. Some of the larger bombers can take out two without reloading. No idea how much the Runway requires but it's at least 50 Tons

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [wiki](http://warthunder.wikia.com/wiki/Bomber) it seems that bombers are a key essential to winning.

> Heavy Bombers are the pinnacle of target bombing. They contain the
>   largest bomb loads of all the bombers with around 2000kg up to 5000kg
>   worth of bombs. With about 5-9 turrets, every bomber is a flying
>   fortress. The main point of the heavy bomber class is to destroy
>   several groups in a single run, or even go after the coveted base
>   destroyer.

There is a video below to show the importance of the bomber. But, because of it's power and load capacity the heavy bomber can wipe out tons of units which paves the way to victory.

Comment: This doesn't address any of the problems that the question poses... Not even one.

Comment: The video does, but a 4 chapter video series should be explained and summarized, not just posted as your answer.

Comment: Why does wiping out tons of units pave the way to victory? Seems to me it just gets you a few points, and does absolutely nothing for your team.

Comment: @happyGamer222 Every time you take out an enemy unit the enemy loses victory points (red/blue bar @ top of screen). The ratio of ground/sea units on each team also causes one side "bleed" VP.  The alrger the difference, the quicker points are eroded. Bombing bases removes a noticeable quantity of VP and destroying the runway causes the VP to drop so rapidly, they lose a few seconds later. In short, bombers can win the game in very short order - literally minutes if they know what they're doing and work together - but it's quite hard to stay alive that long without good fighter support.

Answer (score 0):

Some games, especially those containing large maps, will have objectives/enemies that can only be taken out by bombers. With that in mind, some bases can be defeated faster with this type of planes.